# ListView with Image Adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a List items in List View.if i click on first item i will start the activit and will show some images.If i click in second list item,i will start another activity and will show some set of images.Here is the List View code.
package com.example.per.app;

```
public class AlbumListActivity extends Activity {

    public String[] mListInfo = { "1st Month", "2nd Month", "3rd Month",
            "4th Month", "5th Month", "6th Month", "7th Month", "8th Month",
            "9th Month", "10th Month", "11th Month", "12th Month" };
    public ListView mList = null;
    public Intent mLaunch = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_album);
        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mListInfo);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                switch (arg2) {
                case 0:
                    mLaunch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstMonthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mLaunch);
                }
            }

        });

    }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (arg1 == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(363, 363));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) arg1;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[arg0]);
            return imageView;
        } // references to our images

        Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.sample0, R.drawable.sample1,
                R.drawable.sample2, R.drawable.sample3, R.drawable.sample4,
                R.drawable.sample5, R.drawable.sample6, R.drawable.sample7,
                R.drawable.sample8, R.drawable.sample9 };
    }
}
```

I need to maintain the ImageAdapater class for List items in view?Because for each List item i want to show different set of images.

Currently i added only Case 0 and I will add Case 1 case2 case3...case 12.So i have to launch 12 activities.in each activity i want to display different set of images.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. I think it's not necessary to launch 12 activities. You can write just one activity and when you which to that activity from your list item click then , you can just pass a int array of drawables to be used as image set in your next activity.

Here is a sample code that you can try....

In your list Activity you can keep some Arraylist of drawables like this , so for your case you may require 12 such ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> thumb1list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        thumb1list.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        thumb1list.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        thumb1list.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Then when you click on a list item them then launch your second Activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Second.class);
        intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("key", thumb1list);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Finally in your second activity , catch the above ArrayList of Integer like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> Array = getIntent().getExtras().getIntegerArrayList("key");
```

then , you can load these images in a gridview or anything whatever you like.

Comment: I have 12 items in List.I have 120 images in res folder.For each List item i want to show the 10 images.How to do that?

Comment: See my edited answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: So in My code I used ImageAdaper class to load the images.So that class is not required?Please see in above code.

Comment: You don't need it inside this class. You're just going to use that adapter at your second activity, that is when you want to load your pictures.

Comment: I want to load different pictures for each List item click.So in above code How to declare different images in image adapter in second activity?                                                     Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.sample0, R.drawable.sample1,
                R.drawable.sample2, R.drawable.sample3, R.drawable.sample4,
                R.drawable.sample5, R.drawable.sample6, R.drawable.sample7,
                R.drawable.sample8, R.drawable.sample9 };

Comment: Look at the ArrayList of Integers I have written above. In your first activity you can keep an ArrayList of these Integer ArrayLists. And in your onListItemClick listener you can pick the correct ArrayList containing your required drawables from that "ArrayList of Integer ArrayLists". Then just pass that ArrayList to the intent like I have written above.

Comment: then ImageAdapter is not required? In my code i used ImageAdapter inner class to load the images.Please see in above code.